# LaTeX compile error

Tags: compiling

I am getting this error and i do not know why,
i need to know what it is to be able to work around it.

i have this latex document which has a place holder to take a month and when i am feeding it a month from the terminal it is screaming at me with this error:

```
c_sys_month_int
```

also saying `! Missing number, treated as zero.`

the field is just a normal `renewcommand{\month}{\Month}`

in summary what is `c_sys_month_int` and does it expect a certain formate.

PS when i hardcore the month name into the tex file before compiling, ie `renewcommand{\month}{March}` or `renewcommand{\month}{5}` i get no error in compiling. so why if i feed it the value from terminal it does not work, moreover the document has about 7 other input values being taken from the terminal with no problem.

i have also noticed that i can use batchmode but it will only accept digits for the month and not the word like march may or june.
i am also having this error from time to time: `Package inputenc Warning: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.`

Comment: You should post an MWE, so we can see the errant code. Otherwise, it'll be hard to help you.

Comment: unfortunately, the code is not with me, i can only send the request to the server to print me a pdf, i just want to know what is c_sys_month_int, and ill try to give it the input it is expecting, since it saturday, if i want the code ill have to wait till monday

Comment: Have you tried using a number to represent the month? The `_int` part implies that it expects a number. As does the error message

Comment: yes i tried it says: ! You can't use `the character 5' after \the.
\month

Comment: If you put `\global\errorcontextlines\maxdimen` in your document and post the full error message, it may help us.

Comment: unfortunately, this will have to get postponed to monday, since i can not download the file to my laptop, but thanks for you help

Comment: `\c_sys_month_int` is a LaTeX3 integer which stores the current month. From the documentation `interface3`: "The date and time at which the current job was started: these are all reported as integers. TeXhackers note: Whilst the underlying primitives can be altered by the user, this interface to the time and date is intended to be the “real” values." The leading `c` suggest that it should not be altered (constant), the trailing `int` is the data type. But without the code on how the input is handled I can't do much to get to your error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One can trigger the error with for example

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\Month}{October}
\renewcommand{\month}{\Month}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

The error arises as `\c_sys_month_int` is where `expl3` (the LaTeX3 programming layer) stores a copy of the month from the `\month` *primitive*.  As this is a primitive (part of TeX itself), `expl3` (and many other packages) expect it take be a particular form: an integer in the range [1,12]. Redefining it is not a good idea: if you want to localise the output for *e.g.* `\today`, look at appropriate packages.

Comment: so in other words, \month is a reserved variable to that pacakge and if i want to feed it from terminal with custom values that i want it should have another name so that it does not use its package ?>

Comment: @Hazo you could write a wrapper, which takes the month's name you want and returns its number.

Comment: @Hazo Well nothing in TeX is 'reserved' but it's a bad idea to alter such things.